# Autolayout constraint on UIImageView in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm using interface builder to setup my autolayout constraints for my tableview cell. I need the UIImageView to be 100% width of the cell. The constraint that does this is setting the trailing space equal to the superview. This works, until I add section index titles and then the image moves over to accommodate the width of the section index titles.

How can I fix the autolayout constraint on the UIImageView in order to force it to occupy the full width of the cell, even when the section index titles are displayed? I also made sure to set the background color to clear for the section index titles, so I know the issue is definitely with the image view not going full width.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Based on printing the widths of the contentview of the cell and the imageview to the console, they're both the same when I add the section index titles. So I think I need to somehow add a constraint on the contentView itself to make it the same width as the tableview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same problem while I had the accessory view in my tableview cell. The trick is to get the width of the contentView correct (to which the trailing space of the imageView is set). To achieve this do the following :

In your Custom tableview cell's class, override the **layoutSubviews** method:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews{
 [super layoutSubviews];

 self.contentView.frame = self.bounds;

}
```